# Title cutoff in tabbed page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Tabbed page title cut off in tabbed page in Android

[image]

but working fine in iOS Device

[image]

i am using this code

```
public Tabbar()
        {
            //this.BarTextColor = Color.Maroon;
            // New Feed
            var navigationNewFeed = new NavigationPage(new NewFeedView());
            navigationNewFeed.Title = "News Feed";
            navigationNewFeed.Icon = "news";
            Children.Add(navigationNewFeed);

            // Volunteer View
            var navigationPageVolunteer = new NavigationPage(new VolunteerView());
            navigationPageVolunteer.Icon = "Volunteer";
            navigationPageVolunteer.Title = "Volunteer";
            Children.Add(navigationPageVolunteer);


            // LAH View
            var navigationPageLAH = new NavigationPage(new LAHView());
            navigationPageLAH.Icon = "lah";
            navigationPageLAH.Title = "LAH";
            Children.Add(navigationPageLAH);



            // Notification View
            var navigationPageNotification = new NavigationPage(new NotificationView());
            navigationPageNotification.Icon = "notification";
            navigationPageNotification.Title = "Notification";
            Children.Add(navigationPageNotification);


            // Account View
            var navigationPageAccount = new NavigationPage(new AccountView());
            navigationPageAccount.Icon = "account";
            navigationPageAccount.Title = "Account";
            Children.Add(navigationPageAccount);


        }
```

Comment: Tell me, please, have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194140/is-there-a-way-to-stop-longer-xamarin-shell-tab-titles-being-truncated/62656858#62656858

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a lower text size through `Tabbar.axml` on your Android XF Project, adding **app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
    app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" 
    app:tabGravity="fill" 
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom style and change size of text in the tab. [How to use custom style for tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555554/5912513).

And change style:

```
<style name="CustomTab"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">5sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, **in android, the text is displayed in CAPS by *default***, though you type the First letter in caps and the following words in small (e.g. Button Text "Accept" is however displayed as **ACCEPT**).

To override it and display as you type (i.e., Accept), include this line in your theme file (say in YourProject.Android/Resources/values/styles.xml) that you applied to your android activity

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ............
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Thanks to answers in [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-forced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)

**EDIT :** If you are missing tab title, you can use this below code to solve as it solved mine wonderfully!

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.Design.Internal;
using Android.Views;
using FixedTabbedPage.Droid.CustomRenderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace FixedTabbedPage.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (ViewGroup != null && ViewGroup.ChildCount > 0)
            {
                BottomNavigationMenuView bottomNavigationMenuView = FindChildOfType<BottomNavigationMenuView>(ViewGroup);

                if (bottomNavigationMenuView != null)
                {
                    var shiftMode = bottomNavigationMenuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");

                    shiftMode.Accessible = true;
                    shiftMode.SetBoolean(bottomNavigationMenuView, false);
                    shiftMode.Accessible = false;
                    shiftMode.Dispose();

                    for (var i = 0; i < bottomNavigationMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
                    {
                        var item = bottomNavigationMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                        if (item == null) continue;                         

                        item.SetShiftingMode(false);
                        item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);
                    }

                    if (bottomNavigationMenuView.ChildCount > 0) bottomNavigationMenuView.UpdateMenuView();
                }
            }
        }

        private T FindChildOfType<T>(ViewGroup viewGroup) where T : Android.Views.View
        {
            if (viewGroup == null || viewGroup.ChildCount == 0) return null;

            for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null) return typedChild;

                if (!(child is ViewGroup)) continue;

                var result = FindChildOfType<T>(child as ViewGroup);

                if (result != null) return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Refer : 1) [In Xamarin Forms 3.1, when using tabbed page with 4 tabs, how can I prevent "sliding" effect of tab bar on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864505/in-xamarin-forms-3-1-when-using-tabbed-page-with-4-tabs-how-can-i-prevent-sli)

2) https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/361462#Comment_361462

Thanks to jezh and J.Aguilar

Hope this helps..