# Change TabbedPage Item FontSize on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-size, tabbedpage

I use a TabbedPage with position bottom in my xamarin forms project.

On Android, the font size is too big.

I'm looking for a way to reduce the font size.

I'm also trying to remove the effect that makes the selected menu item bigger.

```xml
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:namespace.Views"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:namespace.Utils;assembly=namespace"
            Title="{Binding Title}"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#002244"
            android:TabbedPage.BarBackgroundColor="White"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#096cd0"
            x:Class="namespace.Views.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Home" Title="{i18n:Translate Menu_Home}" IconImageSource="accueil.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Home />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Services" Title="{i18n:Translate Menu_MyServices}" IconImageSource="services.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MyServices />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Documentation" Title="{i18n:Translate Menu_Documentation}" IconImageSource="documentation.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Documentation />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="VideoCall" Title="{i18n:Translate Menu_Video}" IconImageSource="videoconferenc.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:VideoCall />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

### Here is the result

- #### We're finding that the "videoconsultation" doesn't have enough room.

  [image: Accueil]
- #### It's even worse here

  [image: VideoCall]
- #### The word "services" disappears when selected.

  [image: Services]

I've done a lot of research, but I've found a way to make it work.

When the menu is positioned at the top, I can change some settings in style.xml, but it doesn't seem to work when it's positioned at the bottom.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you very much,

Chris

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915849/title-cutoff-in-tabbed-page-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Also, if it is an issue of font size, you can read the documentations/examples of using <OnPlatform> in the xaml and then you can set a font value for android specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this blog](https://xamgirl.com/extending-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/) to change the `FontSize` of `tabbedPage` item on Android, write a `custom renderer` of `TabbedPage` and change the `textSize` there:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedTabbedPage), typeof(ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace CustomTabbedPage.Droid
{
    public class ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage tabbedPage;
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
        Android.Views.IMenuItem lastItemSelected;
        private bool firstTime = true;
        int lastItemId=-1;
        public ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                tabbedPage = e.NewElement as ExtendedTabbedPage;
                bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;


                //Call to change the font
                ChangeFont();
            }
        }

        //Change Tab font
        void ChangeFont()
        {
            var fontFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "gilsansultrabold.ttf");
            var bottomNavMenuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

            for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var item = bottomNavMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);

                var smallTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0));
                var largeTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1));

                lastItemId = bottomNavMenuView.SelectedItemId;

                //smallTextView.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
                //largeTextView.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Bold);

                smallTextView.TextSize = 18;
                largeTextView.TextSize = 18;

                //Set text color
                var textColor = (item.Id == bottomNavMenuView.SelectedItemId) ? tabbedPage.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().GetBarSelectedItemColor().ToAndroid() : tabbedPage.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().GetBarItemColor().ToAndroid();
                smallTextView.SetTextColor(textColor);
                largeTextView.SetTextColor(textColor);
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Change the `textSize` of `smallTextView` and `largeTextView` will work. You can also download the sample project [here](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ExtendedTabbedPageSample).

Comment: do you know how to split title in 2 lines(MultiLine) for TabbedPage in xamarin ios? I know the solution for multiline Title in contenpage. But when i use multiline Title content pages as tabs of TabbedPage, 2nd line title is not visible

Comment: @Blu I don't know. But I guess it is not possible since there is no enough space for the second line.

Comment: No problem with the spacing, i dont have icons for my tabbedpage n i can even set the padding to tittle text from bottom, so that text can have enough space for multi line.

Answer (score 1):

To change the font size for bottom tabbed page see the below link ...it works for me .Instead of creating custom renderer just follow these steps.

1)Create new file "dimens.xml" in Android -> Resources/Values(only if it doesn't exits)
2)and then copy the code which is in the following link

link :

https://montemagno.com/control-text-size-on-android-bottom-navigation/

Comment: Please put the whole code instead to linking to other website. This is useful in case the external website becomes inaccessible.