# Xamarin Form - How to change TabbedPage title font size in ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I have created a `TabbedPage` with four `ContentPages` as the `TabbedPage.Children` with `Title`. The `Title`s presented in iOS app is perfect and able to read. However, in Android it seems the `Title` font size is too large to be displayed even I change the Preference Font Size in the Android device's setting.

**Here is my TabbedPage XAML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Views;assembly=MyApplication"
            x:Class="Demo.TabbedPageView"
            Title="My Application">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:View One/>
        <local:View Two/>
        <local:View Three/>
        <local:View Four/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

**TabbedPage Screenshot**

**iOS** - https://ibb.co/fmCZcH

**Android** - https://ibb.co/drEQjx

My questions are

1. How can I change the `Title`'s font size in `ResourceDictionary`?
2. Is there any other way to achieve the same goal in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use custom style and change the text size of the tabs.

See this [How to use custom style for tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555554/5912513)

 And change the style:

```xml
<style name="CustomTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">5sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I realise it can only be done by editing from the native project code but not in Xamarin.Form project itself. Anyway, thanks for your answer.